# Restart program/game

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Im working on this random-number-guessing game. At the end of the game I want the user to be given the option of playing again (or letting someone else play). I've found a couple of similar threads and questions but none have been able to help me solve this little issue. Im pretty sure I can use my while-loop someway but dont know exactly how..

Very new to Java so understand if this is an easy fix..

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame {
public static void main(String[] args){

Random rand = new Random();
int correctNumber = rand.nextInt(100);
int numberOfGuesses = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int guess;
boolean win = false;    
String username = "";

    System.out.println("Hello, it is time to play a guessing game.");
    System.out.println("We will generate a random number between 0-99, and you will have to try to guess the number in as few attempts as possible.");
    System.out.println("You can also choose to give up by pressing \"q\" on your keyboard. \n\nTo get started, press \"s\" on your keyboard.");
    input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("\nEnter a username: ");
    username = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\nNew username registered: " + username);


    while(win == false){

    System.out.println("\nGuess a number between 0-99: ");
    guess = input.nextInt();
    numberOfGuesses++;

    if (guess == correctNumber){
        win = true;
    }
     else if(guess < correctNumber){
        System.out.println("Too low. Try again!");   
    }else if(guess > correctNumber){
        System.out.println("Too high. Try again!");   
    }
    }

    System.out.println("\nYou guessed the correct number which was " + correctNumber + ". Congrats!");
    System.out.println("\n" + username + " your number of guesses were: " + numberOfGuesses);

    win = false;
        }

 //     System.out.println("\nTo play again (let someone else try) press      \"s\", to quit press \"q\".");
 //     input.nextLine();
  //    if (input.next().equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
 //     System.out.println("\nThanks for playing!");
 //     }
 //     }else if(input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("s")){       

    }

 //}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is called a "game loop".  Basically you'd wrap your entire game in a loop which would repeat based on some condition.  In this case the condition is whether or not the user wants to play again.

In Java-ish pseudo-code, the structure would look like this:

```
boolean keepPlaying = true;
while (keepPlaying) {

    boolean hasWon = false;
    while (!hasWon) {
        // play a round in the game
    }

    keepPlaying = promptUser("Would you like to play again?");
}
```

The "pseudo" part of that pseudo-code of course being that last line.  Simply ask the user if they'd like to play again, and convert the response to the logical value being used by the game loop.

So the game itself is a loop of "rounds" which repeat until a win or loss has occurred.  And the *program* is a loop of "games" which repeat until the user quits.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick answer I tried implementing that but didnt work. If I might ask, shouldnt (something) like this work?       System.out.println("\nTo play again (let someone else try) press \"s\", to quit press \"q\".");
     input.nextLine();
     if ( input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
      win = false;
      }else{
       System.out.println("\nThanks for playing!");
      }

Comment: @EricPlayer: Without knowing the larger context of the code you're using, it's tough to say.  Though it doesn't seem semantically right that the `win` variable (which implies to me the inner loop) would be driven by that "play again?" prompt (which would drive the outer loop).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

    public class GuessingGame {
       public static void main(String[] args){

       Random rand = new Random();
       int correctNumber = rand.nextInt(100);
       int numberOfGuesses = 0;
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       int guess;
       boolean win = false;    
       String username = "";
       String choice = "No"; //new Variable

System.out.println("Hello, it is time to play a guessing game.");
System.out.println("We will generate a random number between 0-99, and you    will have to try to guess the number in as few attempts as possible.");
System.out.println("You can also choose to give up by pressing \"q\" on your keyboard. \n\nTo get started, press \"s\" on your keyboard.");
input.nextLine();

System.out.println("\nEnter a username: ");
username = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("\nNew username registered: " + username);

do{
while(win == false){

System.out.println("\nGuess a number between 0-99: ");
guess = input.nextInt();
numberOfGuesses++;

if (guess == correctNumber){
    win = true;
}
 else if(guess < correctNumber){
    System.out.println("Too low. Try again!");   
}else if(guess > correctNumber){
    System.out.println("Too high. Try again!");   
}
}

System.out.println("\nYou guessed the correct number which was " + correctNumber + ". Congrats!");
System.out.println("\n" + username + " your number of guesses were: " + numberOfGuesses);

win = false;
//added the next two lines
System.out.println("Do you want to play again?  Type \'Yes\' to play again or \'No' to quit");
choice = input.next();
}

     while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));

    }

 //     System.out.println("\nTo play again (let someone else try) press 
 \"s\", to quit press \"q\".");
   //     input.nextLine();
    //    if (input.next().equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
     //     System.out.println("\nThanks for playing!");
     //     }
     //     }else if(input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("s")){       

  }

 //}
```